# Mot français pour « craft »

Tags: traduction, anglais, demande-de-mot

Voici la phrase que j'essaie de traduire : « Programming is a craft. »

Littéralement : « La programmation est un métier ».

Pour moi, « craft » ne se limite pas à la notion de métier, j'y vois également une notion d'artisanat, d'art. (Ai-je raison ?)

Y a-t-il un mot français au sens similaire ?

Comment: Pour la notion d'artisanat, je suis assez d'accord, pour moi les programmeurs sont de nouveaux artisans du 21ème siècle...

Comment: Comme indiqué par @Gilles, "Art" porte à confusion. Je proposerai **La programmation est un travail de maître artisan**, bien que le titre de maître artisan ait (en France) une définition légale qui n'a de sens que dans le cadre des métiers de l'artisanat.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Je traduirais cette phrase :

> La programmation est un art.

[**Art**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/art) ne désigne pas ici uniquement le domaine artistique mais est utilisé aussi avec son sens premier (*I.-* dans la définition du tlfi) qui correspond le mieux à ***craft*** dont la [définition dans le Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craft) est ici :

*a :  an occupation or trade requiring manual dexterity or artistic skill*

Un article précisément intitulé *[Programming is a craft](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/programming-craft-david-acevedo)* parle d'ailleurs de chef d'oeuvre :

*The beauty of a program comes from its functionality as much as its cleverness. Like a house. It can be beautiful and architecturally brilliant, but if it fails as a house it fails, however if the architecture enhances the house, then it's a masterpiece.*

Comment: C'est tout le sens I qui est présent, pas seulement I.C. La citation de C. Bernard peu se transposer de la médecine à la programmation, et devrait vraisemblablement pour faire passer l'intention de la phrase anglaise parce qu'il y a une esthétique de la programmation et que simplement "La programmation est un art." sans un contexte clair pourrait être compris comme une allusion à cette esthétique.  Voir aussi l'expression "Homme de l'art" qui ne désigne pas un artiste, mais quelqu'un qui maîtrise une technique.

Comment: @Unfrancophone C'est vrai, réponse mise à jour. Merci pour ce commentaire.

Comment: Euh? Non, ça serait un contresens complet ! Ici « art » serait compris comme artistique, pas dans son sens devenu très rare d'exercice de l'intelligence et de l'habileté humaines.

Comment: @Gilles D'une part, il ne s'agirait pas d'un contresens total, craft incluant à la fois la notion de dextérité (fait main) et une composante artistique, et d'autre part Il faudrait une audience bien peu informée pour imaginer que la programmation est une discipline purement artistique. Il ne me semble pas que le sens large d'art soit si désuet. Tout le monde comprend que « l'art d'accommoder les restes » n'est pas une discipline enseignée à l'Ecole des beaux-arts ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Ben non. Ça se voit particulièrement si on essaie de traduire « The Craft of Computer Programming », qui est le titre de plusieurs articles et au moins un livre — titre qui vise à contraster avec le célèbre « The Art of Computer Programming ».

Comment: @Gilles Je comprends cette réticence mais je n'oppose pas *craft* à *art*, les deux représentent la même notion : travail manuel de qualité qui résulte de la maîtrise technique d'auteurs faisant preuve de créativité, à un degré moindre pour *craft*, supérieur pour *art*. Le mot français art englobe ces deux sens. *Craft* comme *art* s'opposent à une approche déterministe, un assemblage préfabriqué où la créativité et l'adresse n'ont pas leur place. Il faudrait plus de contexte pour en être sûrs mais je ne pense pas que la phrase en question signifie "Programming is a craft (but not an art)".

Comment: @jlliagre Si, le sens de ce titre était justement de dire que la programmation est quelque chose de raisonné obéissant à des règles, contrairement à un art qui obéit à l'esthétique et n'est pas quantifiable. L'anglais *art* a la même ambiguïté qu'en français, mais l'opposer à *craft* crée clairement une opposition.

Comment: @Gilles Je veux bien croire que c'est le cas dans l'ouvrage « The Craft of Computer Programming » mais rien n'indique que *craft* est opposé à *art* dans la phrase faisant l'objet de la question, « Programming is a craft. »

Comment: Cet échange entre @Gilles et jlliagre est très intéressant. Gilles, aurais-tu une proposition de traduction ? Graffito propose "La programmation est un travail de maître artisan", ce qui me semble un peu long. Peut être plus simplement "La programmation est un travail d'artisan" ?

Answer (score 4):

Le mot anglais *craft* désigne ici une compétence technique, souvent mais pas nécessairement en lien avec l'habileté manuelle, et avec en général l'implication que l'on construit quelque chose. Il se distingue notamment de *science* par le fait que la science est impersonnelle et extrinsèque (elle peut par exemple se transmettre par les livres) alors que *craft* a un aspect personnel et demande un apprentissage par la pratique. Cela correspond précisément à ce qui caractérise l'artisan ; d'ailleurs *craftsman* se traduit en général par *artisan*.

Le français n'a malheureusement pas de mot qui signifie exactement « ce qui caractérise l'artisan ». Le mot français *art*, tout comme son pendant anglais, a deux sens : le sens qui est largement dominant en anglais et en français moderne, l'art de l'artiste, qui est déterminé par l'esthétique et que la plupart des philosophes considère comme non réductible au pur rationnel mais nécessitant de l'inspiration ; et un sens plus général, l'art de l'artisan voire du savant, qui peut couvrir *craft* et *science*, que l'on retrouve dans des expressions comme « homme de l'art », « art de la guerre », …

Dans certains contextes, *art* peut être une bonne traduction de *craft*. Un *craftsman* est un artisan.  Mais ce n'est le cas que si le contexte exclut l'interprétation de *art* comme celui de l'artiste. Or ce n'est pas le cas ici.

Un des traités de programmation les plus célèbres est [*The Art of Computer Programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) de Donald Knuth. Knuth joue sur l'ambiguïté du mot *art*, et met en valeur tantôt l'aspect scientifique, tantôt l'aspect technique, tantôt l'aspect artistique. Or d'autres informaticiens ont voulu se démarquer de sa vision de la programmation, et la présenter comme un savoir transmissible par apprentissage, qui peut nécessiter de l'inspiration pour parvenir à une réalisation mais dont l'inspiration ne transpire pas forcément dans le produit final. Je pense que plusieurs auteurs y sont parvenus indépendamment au titre *The Craft of Computer Programming* ; je citerai notamment le manuel d'apprentissage de la programmation *[The Craft of Computer Programming](https://books.google.fr/books?id=lJZOfQ5p7T0C&dq=%22craft+of+computer+programming%22&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y)* de Craig Jensen et l'article « [The Craft of Computer Programming](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1920789) » sur l'apprentissage de la programmation de Donald House, Brian A. Malloy et Cory Buckley.

Traduire *craft* par *art* gommerait ici cette nuance importante, ce n'est donc pas une traduction appropriée. Les phrases « *programming is an art* » et « *programming is a craft* » n'ont pas le même sens.

Traduire *craft* par *métier* ne convient ici pas non plus. Le mot *métier* impliquerait que le programmeur y consacre sa vie, ou en tout cas une part importante, alors qu'on ne retrouve pas du tout cette nuance dans *craft*.

Je propose [savoir-faire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/savoir-faire) : « la programmation est un **savoir-faire** ». Ce n'est pas tout à fait correct — on devrait plutôt dire que la programmation *manifeste* d'un savoir-faire — mais je pense que l'on comprend bien ce que signifie la phrase anglaise.

Une autre manière de le dire serait que « la programmation est un **travail d'artisan** ». Mais je trouve cette formulation un peu trop indirecte, même si elle convient au niveau du sens.

Comment: Je lis *« Mais ce n'est le cas que si le contexte exclut l'interprétation de art comme celui de l'artiste. **Or ce n'est pas le cas ici**. »* mais la question initiale n'indique aucun contexte ou lien permettant de savoir ce que son auteur souhaite réellement exprimer. Ceci-dit, « savoir faire » est une bonne traduction, en particulier si l'auteur souhaite écarter le côté artistique de la programmation, ce qui reste pour moi encore à démontrer.

Comment: @Jérôme - Avec "savoir-faire": *la programmation demande un savoir-faire*. Ou si le contexte s'y prête:  *la programmation demande un tour de main particulier*.